# STM32 - ESP8266 download file

Tags: stm32

i'm using STM32 as my microprocessor along with I2C EEPROM for storage and ESP8266 for Wifi

How can i download an update binary for the bootloader to flash using ESP8266 although the firmware file will be larger than STM32 Ram so i can't load the file from the ESP8266 in one chunk ?

Comment: Tried splitting it into small chunks and saving it somewhere? [This](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/25945/how-to-read-and-write-eeprom-in-esp8266) is a Arduino example, but you could port it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you want to update the stm32 firmware.

In this case allow to upload a new binary for the stm32 to the web, store it in the esp8266  file system (it must be bigger than stm32 flash size).

After that, enable flash memory writing, set an small protocol for update stm32 from serial comm from esp8266 the file to stm32 flash.

Remember that all functions that are used to update the stm32 flash must be in RAM.

I'm doing a project for stm32f4 and esp8266 and I will do exactly this.

OPTION 2:

If your program binary size is under 50% of stm32 flash size, then use the above half of the stm32 flash memory to store the new program, after reset, check if there is something there, and if it is then update (this is what i'm doing actually in stm32, very secure method to update since only stm32 cpu is used for update and it is very fast).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have two firmwares on the STM32 flash. First one is boot loader and the second one is your application. Your boot loader gets new firmware over serial interface of the ESP8266; so you can use flow control pins to halt communication until you write the data into flash memory.

Answer (score 0):

I use that combination, stm32 and esp32/esp8266, for now i have not used firmware upgrade from esp (my stm32 supports it but I have not needed it for now).

The easier way is to set a serial protocol between both cpus. I'm using half of the stm32 memory for code and half for updating. What I do actually is using the communication protocolo is copy the file to the upper half of the flash memory. After when i reset the code i check if there is a firmware ready to be updated, then I copy from top half of flash to bottom half.

With this system, you can check if all is ok and the update process with take few ms. After you have this system tested (using for example a PC) you can try to do it from your esp, but it is just as easy as repeat the process.

My tip about the esp8266 is to download the file to a spiffs. If you are not using spiffs, use it, create a drive a little bigger than your memory.. for example if your stm32 firmware binary is around 60kb, and your target cpu is 256, use around 160kb for it.

There is another way, it is download the html file in chunks and then send them to the top half of the cpu, it is not very complex. I would requests chunks with the same size of the block size of your comunnication process (in my case i'm using 256b or 512b, i dont remember at this moment).

Anyways if you have enough spiffs size download the file, update the stm32 cpu, delete the file and send a reboot.

Dont forget to add a crc for data transmision between stm32 and esp8266

Btw you dont need to download it to ram , since update is used rarely and you have limitations like number of times that you can update a flash memory, so, it is not a problem to save it to flash in the esp8266 neither the stm32

Best regards